# call jar file from c++- how to get and send args

Tags: java, c++, jar, jvm, java-native-interface

i have the next code that call jar file from c++

```
// helloworld.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <stdexcpt.h>
#include "jni.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

#pragma comment (lib,"C:\\Users\\Hilla\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\helloworld\\helloworld\\jvm.lib")

int main()

{  
    JavaVM *jvm;
    JNIEnv *env;
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;

    JavaVMOption options;

    options.optionString="-Djava.class.path=hilla.jar";

    vm_args.version=JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    vm_args.nOptions=1;
    vm_args.options=&options;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized=0;
    int ret=JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm,(void**)&env,&vm_args);

    jclass cls=env->FindClass("hilla1");
    jmethodID meth = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");

        env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, meth, 0);
    int a;
    cin>>a;
    return ret;



}
```

i want to send and get args from the jar file how can i done it?

my java code is:

```
public class hilla1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello");


    }

}
```

i try to send some args by:
 env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, meth, '56');
but it didnt works
thanks for the help

Comment: All you want is to start the java program? Don´t use JNI...

Comment: i need to send some parameter at JAVA class ans get one

Comment: The main-parameter `String[] args`? Yes, don´t use JNI.

Comment: who can i return string from jar without using JNI?

Answer (score 3):

This won't work:

```
 env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, meth, '56')
```

There are a few problems with it:

1. No Java methods accept a literal string and JNI does not convert any literal string arguments to Java method arguments for you. It is true that several JNI functions accept *modified UTF-8* strings but they operate on a limited set of strings, such as class and method signatures, where we rely on the C++ compiler's destination character set encoding having the same values as modified UTF-8. (Java allows any Unicode currency character to be used in an identifier, so not all signatures can be used in this way because the modified UTF-8 encoding for some currency characters doesn't match any other encoding.)
2. Your method accepts a single argument: `String[]`. The vararg/variadic versions of JNI functions are a convenience so you don't have to create an array that contains all the arguments. You still have to pass exactly one argument for each argument your method takes. In this case, it should be a `jobjectArray` that has been initialized with the `jstring`s you want to pass to `main`.
3. You appear to be depending on implicit conversion from the native character set/encoding to Java's Unicode/UTF-16 encoding. You can do this but you have to use the right `java.lang.String` constructor. You always have to know the character set and encoding of strings that you use, either explicitly or that it is the what the JVM knows as the OS-default.

You can create your `String[]` from native strings. The STL `vector<string>` is one of various ways of holding native strings.

```
vector<string> programArgs;
programArgs.push_back("one");
programArgs.push_back("two");
programArgs.push_back("three");
```

To convert from the native strings to `java.lang.String`, you can take advantage of the `String(byte[])` constructor using the OS-default character set and encoding.

```
jclass stringClass = env->FindClass("java/lang/String");
jmethodID stringCtor = env->GetMethodID(stringClass, "<init>", "([B)V");

int argsCount = programArgs.size();
jobjectArray mainArgs = (jobjectArray) env->NewObjectArray(
  argsCount, 
  stringClass, 
  nullptr);

for (int i = 0; i < argsCount; i++) {
    string programArg = programArgs[i];
    int length = programArg.length();
    jbyteArray argBytes = env->NewByteArray(length);
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(
      argBytes, 
      0, 
      length, 
      reinterpret_cast<const jbyte *>(programArg.data()));
    jstring argString = reinterpret_cast<jstring>(
      env->NewObject(stringClass, stringCtor, argBytes));
    env->SetObjectArrayElement(mainArgs, i, argString);
}

jclass mainClass = env->FindClass("hilla1");
jmethodID mainMethod = env->GetStaticMethodID(
  mainClass, 
  "main", 
  "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");

env->CallStaticVoidMethod(mainClass, mainMethod, mainArgs);
```

Answer (score 0):

when I am using the function FindClass 
if my class "hilla1" is located at the folder a package b i am writnig:

```
jclass mainClass = env->FindClass("a/src/b/hilla1");
```

?